# referring to variables in sql in R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

Any hints as to why this doesn't work.  Is it because from is a keyword?

```
join_1 <- sqldf("select distinct ds1.from  from ds1
                except
                select distinct ds2.name from ds2")
```

> Error: near "from": syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your code that `ds1.from` is a column name in the data frame `ds1`.

Try putting the column names in square brackets.

```
library(sqldf)

join_1 <- sqldf("select distinct [ds1.from] from ds1
                 except
                 select distinct [ds2.name] from ds2")
```

Answer (score 0):

`from` must be escaped as it is a keyword.

```
join_1 <- sqldf("select distinct ds1.[from]  from ds1
                except
                select distinct ds2.name from ds2")
```